# Differentiate between var from above block and let variable in a block with the same name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a situation like this:

```js
var menu="VarMenu"
{
  let menu="LetMenu";
  console.log(menu);
}
```

The problem is that I want to access the menu variable declared with var with value "VarMenu" inside the block. Is it possible?
A similar(but conceptually different) way in C++ is to use the scope resolution operator.
Please Help. Hope the question is not a duplicate.

For those who are wondering what it's need is.. Well I had written a menu variable earlier and now I need all of the code that I used inside a block for it but assign to a new let variable(which is a problem that I came across while making menu interface.. I just need another enclosing div for the menu content).

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Afaik, it's not possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use a different variable name?

Comment: It's just scopes. `var` ads variables to the global scope. So you could access it with `window['menu']`

Comment: Well I had written a menu variable earlier now I need all of the code that I used inside a block for it but assign to a new let variable.

Comment: @icecub  `var ads variables to the global scope.`,  it does if you happen to be in the global scope, otherwise it adds it to the `function` scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I want to access the menu variable declared with var with value "VarMenu" inside the block. Is it possible?

Not if the code shown is anywhere other than global scope¹ (so: in a function, in a module, etc.). The `menu` inside the block completely shadows the `menu` outside the block. You cannot access it.

**Your best bet is to change the name of one or the other.**

Just for completeness, a very much **worse** idea is to define a function that can get the outer `menu`'s value. (E.g., `function getMenu() { return menu; }` defined outside the block and called within it.) I don't recommend it if you can avoid it. :-)

---

¹ **If** the code shown is at global scope, `var menu` creates a global variable, and `var` globals are also properties of the global object, which you can access via `globalThis` (in modern environments) or `window` (on browsers). So you could use `globalThis.menu` or `window.menu` inside the block to access it. But **only** if the code shown is at global scope.